# Problemas con carga de datos con Php y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema raro, resulta que tengo un formulario de carga de personal, y si copio en nombre y apellido de otra pagina no carga la persona, se hace el proceso, dice persona cargada con exito pero no aparece en la base de datos, pero si escribo manualmente si, se carga bien-
Estoy usando php y mysql para insertar los datos en la base de datos.

Les dejo el insert para que vean que simple es:

**tengo la validacion de la variable de session:**

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user"]) || (!empty($_SESSION["usuario"]) && $_SESSION["user"] !== 'admin' && $_SESSION["usuario"] !== 'usuario')) {
    $_SESSION["nombre_scout"];
    header("Location: entrar.html");
  exit();
}
```

**Y EL INSERT**

```
//RECIBO LAS VARIABLES DEL FORMULARIO
$apellido = isset($_POST['apellido']) ? $_POST['apellido'] : NULL;
$nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
$fec_nac = isset($_POST['fec_nac']) ? $_POST['fec_nac'] : NULL;
$puesto = isset($_POST['puesto']) ? $_POST['puesto'] : NULL;
$altura = isset($_POST['altura']) ? $_POST['altura'] : NULL;

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO personal (apellido, nombre, fec_nac, puesto, altura) VALUES (UPPER('$apellido'), UPPER('$nombre'), '$fec_nac', '$puesto', '$altura')");
mysqli_close($conn);
header('Location:personal-registrado-exitoso.php');
```

cargar-personal.php

**VARIABLE DE SECCION**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user"]) || (!empty($_SESSION["usuario"]) && $_SESSION["user"] !== 'admin' && $_SESSION["usuario"] !== 'usuario')) {
    $_SESSION["nombre_scout"];
    header("Location: entrar.html");
  exit();
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4"><!--APELLIDO-->
<label for="apellido" class="form-label"><strong>Nombre</strong></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellido" name="apellido" required placeholder="">
<div class="invalid-feedback">Ingrese el apellido</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><!--NOMBRE-->
<label for="nombre" class="form-label"><strong>Nombre</strong></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" required placeholder="">
<div class="invalid-feedback">Ingrese el Nombre</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4"><!--FECHA DE NACIMIENTO-->
<label for="fec_nac" class="form-label"><strong>Fecha de nacimiento</strong></label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="fec_nac" name="fec_nac" placeholder="" required>
<div class="invalid-feedback">Ingrese fecha de nacimiento.</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4"><!--PUESTO-->
<label for="puesto" class="form-label"><strong>Puesto</strong></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="puesto" name="puesto" required placeholder="">
<div class="invalid-feedback">Ingrese el puesto</div>
</div>
        
<div class="col-md-3"><!--ALTURA--> 
<label for="altura" class="form-label"><strong>Altura</strong></label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="altura" name="altura" placeholder="CM" required>
<div class="invalid-feedback">Ingrese el altura.</div>
</div>
```

Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema? No se si sera la variable de session

Otra cosa rara, es que algunos escribiendo tampoco carga en la base de datos, pero me dice cargado con exito, y otra cosa ese mismo que no se pudo cargar lo cargo con un generico como por ejemplo nombre pepe apellido pepe y se carga ahi voy a editar y puedo editar con el nombre real :(

Muy raro, el tema es que localmente no me hace nada de eso.

Comment: Mira que es lo que le llega a tu archivo procesador (el que inserta). Lo más probable es que se copie con algún formato. Copia > Pega en un Notepad > Copia de ahí > Pega en tu form y prueba. PD: Si no hay nada en la DB y tu código dice que si, tienes otro error que debes verificar...

Comment: Tienes que incluir el código del formulario.

Comment: Ahi inclui el codigo hmtl @Alfabravo

Comment: Hay páginas que tienen mecanismos "anticopia" y algunas, por ejemplo, insertan caracteres "extraños" en los textos. Posiblemente cuando copias y pegas desde esa otra página esté sucediendo eso. Has un `var_dump($_POST)` en la página donde capturas el formulario a ver si está pasando correctamente la información. Si no se ve nada raro, posiblemente haya caracteres invisibles, en ese caso tendrás que crear un filtro para el texto.

Comment: No es evidente cómo estás instanciando las variables de sesión. Tampoco es evidente cómo se crean las variables que usas en el INSERT. Qué es `$apellido` y dónde se le asigna un valor? Falta información en tu post.

Comment: @Alfabravo ahi edite la pregunta

Comment: El gran problema que veo en tu código es lo que yo llamo *programación optimista o ingenua*. Has escrito un programa pensando que las cosas siempre irán bien. No implementas ningún control de errores. Ahora el programa te dice *persona cargada con éxito*, pero no es cierto. Una persona cargada con éxito supone que hubo al menos una fila afectada en la consulta. No estás controlando eso y ese es tu error de ingenuidad aquí. Debes controlar todos los posibles errores en tu programa, aplicando lo que yo llamo *programación pesimista*, que piensa en todos los fallos posibles para salirles al paso.

Comment: @A.Cedano eso es cierto, no soy ningun experto por eso busco ayuda, ustyed plantea el probelma pero no la soluicion. ¿como podria solicionar eso?

Comment: Lo que mencionas al final es por lo que comentan acá: rediriges a exitoso sin importar qué haga el query. Claro que va a decir exitoso siempre. Programación defensiva, le decimos por acá. Validar qué retorna mysqli_query o de qué va la inserción para ver qué haces. Lo otro, seguimos sin saber cómo envías esos input. Están dentro de un form? Usas javascript?

Comment: Y no hablo sólo de errores en el código o en los datos, sino también en la lógica. Por ejemplo, si la tabla tiene restricciones y la consulta viola alguna de ellas (filas duplicadas, not null, integridad referencial, etc), en este caso  todo parecerá ir normal, porque no controlas nunca el resultado de haber llamado a `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: @Alfabravo no uso javascript , lo envio desde un form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes comprobar que la query se ha hecho con éxito:

```
$insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO personal (apellido, nombre, fec_nac, puesto, altura) VALUES (UPPER('$apellido'), UPPER('$nombre'), '$fec_nac', '$puesto', '$altura')");
```

Si se ha insertado, `$insert` será TRUE:

```
if($insert) {
  header('Location:personal-registrado-exitoso.php');
} else {
  //Mostrar error
}
```